# How Upload file from Front-end Angular to java API in data base

Tags: java, mysql, angular, spring-boot

Looking to Upload file from Front-end Angular to java API spring Boot in my dataBase Mysql.

My problem it's in my front i have try to convert file to Byte[]

Try also to add setter with file but hibernate  thow exception.

->
Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type
[[simple type, class com.upninjaback.model.Ninja]]:
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException:
Conflicting setter definitions for property "picture":
com.upninjaback.model.Ninja#setPicture(1 params) vs com.upninjaback.model.Ninja#setPicture(1 params)

```java
//model
@Entity
public class ninja implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String description;
    private String website;
@Lob
 @Column(name = "picture", columnDefinition="BLOB")
    private byte[] picture;
...

}
// controller
@PutMapping(value="/Ninja")
    public Ninja  updateNinja(@RequestBody Ninja c) {
        return ninjaRepository.save(c);
    }
```

```js
/* html*/
<!-- Image-->
<mat-form-field class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
   <mat-label>Image</mat-label>
      <ngx-mat-file-input formControlName="image" multiple="false" accept="image/*" >
      </ngx-mat-file-input>
</mat-form-field>
/* ts */
public onSave() {
  this.frontDynamic.submitted = true;
  if (this.frontDynamic.updateNinja.invalid) {
    return;
  } else {
    const formValue = this.frontDynamic.updateNinja.value;
    const newNinja = new Ninja(formValue['nom']);
    newNinja.address = formValue['adresse'];
    newNinja.description = formValue['description'];
    newNinja.website = formValue['site'];
    console.log(formValue['image']);
    newNinja.picture =   formValue['image'];
    let image = formValue['image'];
    if (image && image.size > 0) {
      let file = image[0];
      let formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file', file);
      newNinja.picture =   formData;
     }
    this.ninjaService.putNinja(newNinja)
      .subscribe(response => {
        }, error => {
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
  }
}
```

"
Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of [B out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of [B out of START_OBJECT token at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 80] (through reference chain: com.upninjaback.model.Ninja["picture"])]
"

Try with multipart ->

```java
// controller
@PutMapping(value="/Ninja")
    public Ninja  updateNinja(@RequestBody Ninja c,@RequestBody MultipartFile file) {
        try {
        c.setPicture(file.getBytes());
        } catch(Exception e) {}
        return ninjaRepository.save(c);
    }
```

```js
// service
 public putNinja(data, file: File) {
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);
    let url = this.host + '/Ninja/';
    return this.http.put(url, {data, formData},{
      headers: this.headers,
      reportProgress: true,
      responseType: 'json'
    });
  }
/* ts */
public onSave() {
  this.frontDynamic.submitted = true;
  if (this.frontDynamic.updateNinja.invalid) {
    return;
  } else {
    const formValue = this.frontDynamic.updateNinja.value;
    const newNinja = new Ninja(formValue['nom']);
    newNinja.address = formValue['adresse'];
    newNinja.description = formValue['description'];
    newNinja.website = formValue['site'];
    this.ninjaService.putNinja(newNinja,formValue['image']).subscribe(response => {}, error => {console.log(error);});
  }
}
```

Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): com.upninjaback.model.Ninja; nested exception is org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): com.upninjaback.model.Ninja] with root cause

org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): com.upninjaback.model.Ninja

Comment: What error hibernate throws, could you share please?

Comment: Well, probably there is something wrong with your Ninja class methods. Could you share its getters and setters too, by editing the question.

Comment: there is nothing wrong in my Ninja class as I said I tried to create a setter with the prototype file hence the hibernate error

Comment: Use multipart and change your rest service to handle that. Besides, the picture atribute is an array so you need to use @Lob @Column(name = "picture", columnDefinition="BLOB") annotations.

Comment: i edit my question but i don't no how use multipart